# Dealing with security on IPC remoting channel

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, ipc

I am trying to run a service under a different user account from the application that will access the service via remoting.

While under the same account everything is fine, but as soon as I use different accounts, I get an access denied error while trying to open the IPC port.

Is there something I am missing, as I can't see from the MSDN docs what is supposed to be done.

Thanks

Comment: Is the user account you are trying to use a member of the group specified in the authorizedGroups attribute in the channel definition?

Comment: @S.Skov: Nope, I'll try that  :)

Comment: @S.Skov: That worked :)  Make an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close:

Is the user account you are trying to use a member of the group specified in the authorizedGroups attribute in the channel definition? – S.Skov

(Dont upvote)

Answer (score 2):

FYI

Here is a link to the MSDN page that defines the authorizedGroup attribute: [Server Channel Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397831%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and here is the article on [Authentication with the IPC Channel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172351%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

The key paragraph is

> When an IpcServerChannel is created, an Access Control List (ACL) 
>   is created for the channel. By default, the ACL only contains the credentials 
>   the server application is running under. To communicate with the channel, the
>   client (and therefore the IpcClientChannel) must run under the same
>   credentials. You can, however, specify a Windows user or User group in
>   the IPC server channel configuration that allows that user or group of
>   users to access the channel.